# Poor "audit" test on first post audit

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-review-audits, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I disagree with this audit:

[image: image of audit]

[Link to audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20913164)

Original question: [Webhook configuration with Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620226/webhook-configuration-with-gitlab/)

The question asked about a webhook, and this answer got rained on for answering about a webhook. The answer is not a link-only answer, it's an example of a webhook URL.

I think it's a fair chance at taking a stab at answering, and it seems nobody else has an answer (that I can see).

It would appear this answer was deleted, where I believe it actually holds some value that I can't try to improve upon, but now I'm unable to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The First Post review queue is a bit more nuanced than some of the other review queue.  Unlike some other queues, the goal of this review queue is to give feedback to new users which means that any issues with a post deserve *some* action, even if it's only an informative comment.

You are correct that this is an answer and maybe didn't deserve deletion.  As you note, "The answer is not a link-only answer, it's an example of a webhook URL."  However, the formatting is pretty bad, and it's not obvious at first glance that the link actually is code in some form.  Formatting the link better so it doesn't render as a clickable link but instead as a template would improve the clarity of the answer.  Additionally, this answer does not explain anything.  At the very least I would have dropped a comment asking the author to explain why their answer works.

So because this was a first post review, I think this audit is fine.  You failed to provide feedback to a new user that their post should have been improved.

Comment: I get where you are coming from, but I can't add a comment on it because the answer was already deleted, plus I did try to upvote the answer which I believe is what triggered the audit to reveal itself.

Comment: You wanted to upvote this short, no explanation post with confusing formatting?

Comment: Upvote and then comment.

Comment: @Logan Not sure upvoting such an answer is no way to help a first timer to make better posts. Had you found the post outside the queue, do as you wish. But I think that this queue is mostly there to help first posters to learn the ropes.

Comment: @Logan Had you tried to comment on the answer, you would have discovered the post was an audit, and this question wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: Ok, I think I actually have 2 parts to my question here then. You're right about how I handled the audit (part 1 I guess), that's fair and I failed it. However, I do think the answer still holds some value and should be brought back (part 2). Should I change my question to reflect this?

Comment: You can ask a new meta question about the deletion of that answer.  That discussion for a [meta-tag:specific-answer] will be more focused on the merits of the answer and whether it should have been deleted.